# ¿Cómo iterar sobre los atributos de una clase en Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Antes, hacía esto en Javascript:

```
function Instancia(options)
{ this.nombre="Pepe";
  this.edad=18;
  this.estatura=176;

  for(k in options){ 
     this[k]=options[k]; 
   }
}

var persona=new Instancia({nombre:"Luis",estatura:180});
console.log(persona.nombre) //Luis
console.log(persona.estatura) //180
```

Es decir, pasaba el objeto options con algunos datos para actualizar el valor de los `this.edad`,`this.nombre`, etc... No necesariamente todos.
Y la forma de actualizar los atributos rápidamente era usando `(for...in)` ya que se podía referenciar cada miembro de `this` como `this[k]`.

Pero ahora, en Typescript, no sé como hacerlo al instanciar una clase, ya que no puedo referenciar cada uno de los atributos de la clase con  `this[k]` (<-- da error)

Quiero hacer lo mismo en el constructor de una clase, es decir:

```
    class Instancia
    {
    let nombre:string;
    let edad:number;
    let estatura:number;

    
    constructor (options:object){ 
    //Quiero iterar sobre options para asignar los valores a los
    //atributos de la clase que correspondan
    //antes lo hacía así:
    //for(var k in options)this[k]=options[k]
   //CON TYPESCRIPT this[k] NO FUNCIONA
        }
    }
```

Por ejemplo, al instanciar la clase haciendo un

```
let persona:Instancia({edad:21,estatura:180})
```

el constructor debe iterar sobre el objeto `options` y asignar los valores a los atributos que tenga, en este caso: `this.edad=21` y `this.estatura=180`

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Pido disculpas y lo he editado intentando explicarme mejor. Mil perdones de nuevo, es mi primer post con dudas. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer esto lo mejor es usar la clase `Object` de la siguiente manera:

```
interface ObjectProps {
  nombre?: string;
  edad?: number;
  estatura?: number;
}

class Instancia {
  nombre?: string;
  edad?: number;
  estatura?: number;

  constructor(options: ObjectProps) {
    Object.assign(this, options);
  }
}

var persona = new Instancia({ nombre: "Luis", estatura: 180 });
console.log(persona.nombre); //Luis
console.log(persona.estatura); //180
```

Ojo que lo mejor cuando uno tiene preguntas sobre Typescript es comentar los tipos que uno está usando. En este caso yo asumí que la `interface` de tus `options` tiene esos valores: `nombre`, `edad`, `estatura`.

Este código funciona porque Typescript asimila `this` y reconoce sus `keys`. Y da por sentado que si algún key de `options` existe en `this` será asignado.

Comment: Funcionó a la primera, mil gracias. Además, funciona incluso sin definir el interface, aunque eso sí, hay que asegurarse que los tipos de datos son correctos al mandarlos en el object.